# Creating site map

Tags: php, html

I am developing an eshop and i have to do a sitemap...
I think that it is good for search engines...
What markup should i use for this? Using a list? `<li>` ?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on websites the best method of displaying your site's page structure is with nested lists, e.g.:

```
<ul id="sitemap">
    <li>Homepage</li>
    <li>News
        <li>Headlines</li>
        <li>Archives</li>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

This could be done with a simple database query if you're using some sort of content management system.

From this, you could also generate XML site maps (which is what others are referring to) that, instead of aiding humans navigate your site, help crawlers such as search engines navigate your site better.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of an XML sitemap?

This could prove useful to you: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sitemaps have a fairly well defined XML protocol to be used: [reference](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php)

Answer (score 0):

Site maps can be created using a very simple XML specification and stores as sitemap.xml:

http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try
http://xmlsitemap.com/

has a bunch of different tools for making them. The drupal one is quite nice!